# Pointer to a structure and TEST operation

Tags: assembly

I have the following assembly line

```
 test byte ptr [esp + 44h], 1
 jmp SomeCode; 
 .....
```

from a further analysis, I know that esp points at wShowWindow of the STARTUPINFO structure. 
I have written the following:

```
STARTUPINFO *esp_pointer;
esp_pointer -> wShowWindow; 
if(*(esp_pointer) != 1){
    SomeCode;
}
```

Is that a right transformation in C ? What do you mean?

best regards,

Comment: esp_pointer -> wShowWindow is located at 0x30 0r 0n48 not at either 0x44 or at 0n44  you have some wrong analysis also when doing STARTUPINFO *esppointer you need to allocate space for the struct with some malloc etc prior to accessing members else you end up with a crash      STARTUPINFOA *psi = ( STARTUPINFOA * ) calloc(1,sizeof(STARTUPINFOA));
    psi->cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    if(psi->wShowWindow )
    {
        printf("foo");
    }

Answer (score 1):

- Don't try to translate assembly to C line by line. You can't.
- The assembly you posted is probably wrong. A `jmp` is an unconditonal jump; what follows after a `test` instruction is normally a `jz` or `jnz` which jump depending on the result of the test.
- You say `esp` points at `wShowWindow`. That would mean `[esp+44h]` points at something way behind the structure, which makes no sense. Maybe what you wanted to say is "I know i have a `STARTUPINFO` structure on the stack at 14h, so `[esp+44h]` should be the `wShowWindow` component" ?
- If you're right with `STARTUPINFO` somewhere on the stack - it can't be directly at `[esp]`, as mentioned -  please make sure `[esp+44h]` is `wShowWindow`, not `dwFlags`, as the `test` operation would make much more sense with the `dwFlags` bitmap than an integer.

All that said, `test` tests if a bit is set; a compare would be a `cmp`. So if you really really want an example in C, it would look something like

```
STARTUPINFO p;
p=(STARTUPINFO *) ((char *) esp+0x14);   // this assumes the structure starts 
                                         // at offset 0x14 from esp
if (p->wShowWindow & 1) {                // access the wShowWindow component at offset
                                         // 0x30 in the structure, which is 0x44 from esp
    ....
}
```

Note i didn't include the `SomeCode`, as the "jump there" might just mean "skip some instructions", and your unconditional jump seems to be wrong anyways.

Please, when posting a question next time, be a bit more precise in what you ask and what you copy/paste.